# Is there a way to add expires header to images with Godaddy shared Linux hosting?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, http-headers, godaddy

I can't find a way to do it. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom script and redirect all your images to that script. It's kind of a big overhead but it works if it's your only option.

For example

http://yoururl.com/img.php?image=banner.jpg

And that script would contain for example:

```
<?php
header('Expires: full_date_comes_here');

echo file_get_contents('images/'.$_GET['image']);
?>
```

Note!!! This is just a dummy example and you should add validation to your script, to prevent attacks using "../" parts etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, mod_expires will work via .htaccess files.  Put this in your .htaccess file:

```
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 day"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 day"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 day"
```

Comment: mod_expires *does not* work in a shared hosting environment. I just tried this and got a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Windows based hosting with godaddy doesnt support .htaccess, you have to use web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif|js|css|ico|swf)$">
    Header set Expires "Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT"
    Header set Cache-Control "public,max-age=315360000"
    Header set Vary "Accept-Encoding"
</FilesMatch>
```

If you want a shorter caching period, remove `Header set Expires` and adjust `Header set Cache-Control`.